# Он отказался покупать пса, хоть бы воры обобрали его до нитки

Tags: синтаксис

*Он отказался покупать пса, **хоть бы воры обобрали его до нитки**.*

Если судить по союзу, то это уступительное придаточное, верно? 
Но если я его перефразирую, то оно мне звучит как условное: ... *даже если бы воры обобрали его до нитки*. 
Скажите, пожалуйста, есть в русском языке что-то подобное - уступительные предложения с дополнительным условным оттенком? 
Если у Вас есть еще название источника с информацией, я очень рада! 
Большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Семантика данного сообщения была бы понятнее, если выразить ее следующим образом:

Он **все равно** отказался **бы** покупать пса, **даже если** воры обобрали бы его до нитки.

Другой вариант:  Хоть бы воры обобрали его до нитки, он все равно отказался бы покупать пса.

Таким образом, **замечания по стилистике** предложенного варианта: (1) добавить вторую частицу БЫ, (2) поставить придаточное в препозицию (для союза ХОТЯ БЫ), (3) использовать дополнительные структурные элементы (всё равно).

**Анализ предложения**

Это придаточное уступительное союзного типа, где в качестве средства связи могут использоваться: союзы ХОТЯ (БЫ), частицы ПУСТЬ/ПУСКАЙ (БЫ), союзный комплекс ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ.

(1) В этом предложении используется **логическое допущение/предположение нежелательного факта**, поэтому оно имеет значение **уступки**, (2) а частицы БЫ  и формант ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ  указывают на **ирреальную** модальность (поэтому и появляется условный союз ЕСЛИ).

Всё это выглядит как "**уступительные предложения с дополнительным условным оттенком".**

Источник: Г. И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (курс лекций)

Comment: дорогая Sibylla, большое спасибо за ответ! я нашла книгу "Синтаксис ... (2005)" и там идет речь про сопоставительно-уступительные, противительно-уступительные и соединительно-уступительные отношения. Скажите пожалуйста с какой страницы Ваш материал?

Comment: У меня издание 2013 года, там стр. 237. А координаты такие: СПП расчлененной структуры, СПП с придаточными уступки, частные грамматические значения, ирреальная (предположительная) уступка.

Comment: искала весь день дигитальную версию 2013 но к сожалению ничего не нашла : ( 
огромное спасибо за Ваш труд и помощь!!! : )